# Hide resize markers in designer using C#?

Tags: c#, user-controls, designer

Usually when you select a control in designer it will show **resize markers** (*little white square boxes*) around it. I want to make my control **non-resizable** , and I partially implemented it by setting the size in **OnPaint** but the markers are still being shown and you can still drag them (but the control returns to it's previous size immetiatedly).

*How do I hide the markers (like a **label** with Autosize on)?*

(I am overriding AutoSize property)

```
    [BrowsableAttribute(true)]
    public override bool AutoSize {
        get
        {
            return autosize;
        }
        set
        {
            autosize = value;
            this.Invalidate();
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671294/c-lock-winform-controls

Comment: No , that is completely different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement a custom designer ([ControlDesigner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.design.controldesigner.aspx)) for your control and then override the `SelectionRules` property.